# Playframework 2 Use websockets for binary transport

Tags: flash, websocket, playframework-2.0, amf

I would like to use websockets with playframework 2.  One of my clients will be using flash.  In the playframework 2, how can I use websockets with binary data (amf).

Could someone point me to some code that implements this, or at least an article that discusses this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one example of binary Websocket with Play 2.0: http://www.smartjava.org/content/binary-websockets-play-20-and-scala-and-bit-op-javacvopencv/

It is Scala code and it uses [Iteratees](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/Iteratees).

Comment: Thanks, the article helped out.